# Python で正規表現を使用し、頭文字と末尾を指定して文字列を取得したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

**実行環境**

Windows 10
Python 3.X

#### やりたいこと

次の文字列を正規表現の `re.findall` を使用して数値とmsとMBの二つの単位までを取得してリスト化したいと考えております。数値までを取得することはできたのですが、単位を取得することができませんでした。

文字列を次のリストのようにするために、頭文字と末尾を同時に取得したいのですが、うまくやり方が
分かりません。初歩的な質問かもしれませんが教えていただけると幸いです。

##### 取得前の文字列

```
'Duration: 123.45 ms\tBilled Duration: 123 ms\tMemory Size: 123 MB\tMax Memory Used: 123 MB\tInit Duration: 1234.56 ms'
```

##### 取得したリスト

```
['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '123 MB', '123 MB', '1234.56 ms']
```

#### 試したこと

正規表現について知らべ、まず、数値までを取得することができました。

```
string = 'Duration: 123.45 ms\tBilled Duration: 123 ms\tMemory Size: 123 MB\tMax Memory Used: 123 MB\tInit Duration: 1234.56 ms'
stringlist = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+|\d+', string)
```

次に、末尾の指定する際に$を使用することは分かっていますので、次のようにコーディングしましたがリストとして何も取得できませんでした。

```
string = 'Duration: 123.45 ms\tBilled Duration: 123 ms\tMemory Size: 123 MB\tMax Memory Used: 123 MB\tInit Duration: 1234.56 ms'
stringlist = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+ms$|\d+ms$', string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
import re

string = 'Duration: 123.45 ms\tBilled Duration: 123 ms\tMemory Size: 123 MB\tMax Memory Used: 123 MB\tInit Duration: 1234.56 ms'
stringlist = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)? .+?)(?=\t|$)', string)
print(stringlist)

# ['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '123 MB', '123 MB', '1234.56 ms']
```

**re.split() を使う場合**

```py
stringlist = re.split(r': |\t', string)[1::2]
print(stringlist)

# ['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '123 MB', '123 MB', '1234.56 ms']
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。正規表現の書き方について質問します。上記のfindallで書かれたものですが、\d+(?:\.\d+)の部分の？は何を指しているのでしょうか。？の意は「直前の文字が全くないか一つだけある」ということは()の外の\d+のことでしょうか。そうなると?の後ろに「：」が来る理由がわかりません。お手数をおかけしますが、今回の正規表現について全体的に解説を頂けるとありがたいです。@metropolis

Comment: `?:` は「文字列を capture しない」という意味になります。例えば、`'(\d+(\.\d+)? .+?)(?=\t|$)'` という正規表現にすると、結果は、`[('123.45 ms', '.45'), ('123 ms', ''), ('123 MB', ''), ('123 MB', ''), ('1234.56 ms', '.56')]` となります。つまり、「小数点以下の文字列を capture しない(抽出しない)」のです。

Comment: `(?=\t|$)` も同様で(これは「先読み」(lookahead)と呼ばれています)、タブ文字は findall の結果には含まれません。

Comment: 正規表現には先読み、後読みという概念があるのですね。勉強になりました。勉強になりました。　一つ目の()の後ろに.+?　があると思いますがこちらはmsかMBのことを指しているという認識で間違いないでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: また、正規表現において「｜」が「または」の意であると認識しているのですが、「かつ」の認識は別の()に記載したものが「かつ」になるという認識であっていますでしょうか？@metropolis

Comment: たびたび申し訳ございません。今回の文字列は\tで区切られていますが、仮に\tで区切られておらず、末尾がms化MBであることを指定しなければならないような文字列であった場合はどのような記載ができますでしょうか？お手数をおかけしますが対応お願いいたします。

Comment: 「一つ目の()の後ろに.+?　があると思いますがこちらはmsかMBのことを指しているという認識で間違いないでしょうか？」はい、そうです。

Comment: 厳密に言えば正規表現に「かつ」(and)に相当する形式はないのですが、今回の場合はそう捉えても構いません。

Comment: 「仮に\tで区切られておらず、末尾がmsかMBであることを指定しなければならないような文字列であった場合」は、`stringlist = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)? (?:ms|MB))', string)` となります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。私にとって正規表現はまだ難しいですが、扱えるようになれば非常に便利ですので覚えられるよう頑張ってまいります。

Answer (score 1):

別に何でもいいのですが、Matchオブジェクトを使う例もあった方がいいと思い回答してみました。(**やりたいことに反してfindallは使ってません**)

## 仮定した仕様

- 符号なし
- 0省略なし
- 科学技術表記なし
- 単位との間にスペースが1つ固定
- 単位はms/MBのみ
- 単位の後に続く文字は見ない
- 単位なしもありとする

### コード

```py
import re
string = 'Duration: 123.45 ms\tBilled Duration: 123 ms\tMemory Size: 123 MB\tMax Memory Used: 123 MB\tInit Duration: 1234.56 ms'
stringlist = [m[0] for m in re.finditer('(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)(?: (ms|MB))?',string)]
print(stringlist)

# ['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '123 MB', '123 MB', '1234.56 ms']
```

### コンセプト

- (Matchオブジェクトにすることで)数字と単位が個別に取得可能

Answer (score 1):

> 次に、末尾の指定する際に$を使用すること

順に追っていくと
まず数字と `'ms'`の間に空白があるので, それを考慮しないとヒットしません
以下は `\s` 指定してるけど, `\s` は SPC以外にタブや改行文字などにもヒットするので, スペースのみなら `\s`をスペースへ置き換えるとよいでしょう

```py
import re
string = 'Duration: 123.45 ms\tBilled Duration: 123 ms\tMemory Size: 123 MB\tMax Memory Used: 123 MB\tInit Duration: 1234.56 ms'
re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\s*ms$|\d+\s*ms$', string)
# ['1234.56 ms']
```

`$`の「末尾」の意味は, (もう少し正確には) **行の末尾**です
単語の末尾ならば `\b` が利用可能
たとえば `re.findall(r'\b単語\b', '単語、英単語')` なら前者のみヒットし `'英単語'`にはヒットしない

```py
re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\s*ms\b|\d+\s*ms\b', string)
# ['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '1234.56 ms']
```

もしくは `'\t'`を改行に置き換え, `re.MULTILINE` を指定すると複数行に対応

```py
re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\s*ms$|\d+\s*ms$', string.replace('\t', '\n'),
              flags=re.MULTILINE)
# ['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '1234.56 ms']
```

`'ms'`, `'MB'` に対応するには

```py
re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+\s*(?:ms|MB)\b|\d+\s*(?:ms|MB)\b', string)
# ['123.45 ms', '123 ms', '123 MB', '123 MB', '1234.56 ms']
```

しかし長くなるので, 数字部分は纏めて `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` のようにするとよいでしょう

```py
re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:ms|MB)\b', string)
```

参考: (docs.python.org) [re --- 正規表現操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html)